# Why doesn't the compiler recognize "exports" when I convert a unit into a standalone project?

Tags: delphi, dll

I have a legacy encryption pas file that I would like to compile into a DLL that I can call from a C# application.

I don't know much about Delphi and am using Delphi XE2.

I’m trying to export the procedure StringHashSHA1.

When trying to build the DLL I get the following Errors:

- Expected BEGIN but received EXPORTS at...
- Undeclared identifier StringHashSHA1 at...

I can’t see where I’m going wrong.
How do I get the following code to compile to a dll?

```
            library encrypt;

            { Important note about DLL memory management: ShareMem must be the
                first unit in your library's USES clause AND your project's (select
                Project-View Source) USES clause if your DLL exports any procedures or
                functions that pass strings as parameters or function results. This
                applies to all strings passed to and from your DLL--even those that
                are nested in records and classes. ShareMem is the interface unit to
                the BORLNDMM.DLL shared memory manager, which must be deployed along
                with your DLL. To avoid using BORLNDMM.DLL, pass string information
                using PChar or ShortString parameters. }

            uses
                ShareMem,
                System.SysUtils,
                System.Classes,
                Windows,
                System.Types;
            //  LbUtils;

            {$R *.res}

            { message digest blocks }
            type
                TMD5Digest  = array [0..15] of Byte;         { 128 bits - MD5 }
                TSHA1Digest = array [0..19] of Byte;         { 160 bits - SHA-1 }

            { message digest context types }
            type
                TLMDContext  = array [0..279] of Byte;       { LockBox message digest }
                TMD5Context  = array [0..87] of Byte;        { MD5 }
                TSHA1Context = record                        { SHA-1 }
                    sdHi    : DWord;
                    sdLo    : DWord;
                    sdIndex : DWord;
                    sdHash  : array [0..4] of DWord;
                    sdBuf   : array [0..63] of Byte;
                end;

            { SHA-1 constants }
            const
                { 5 magic numbers }
                SHA1_A = DWORD( $67452301 );
                SHA1_B = DWORD( $EFCDAB89 );
                SHA1_C = DWORD( $98BADCFE );
                SHA1_D = DWORD( $10325476 );
                SHA1_E = DWORD( $C3D2E1F0 );
                { four rounds consts }
                SHA1_K1 = DWORD( $5A827999 );
                SHA1_K2 = DWORD( $6ED9EBA1 );
                SHA1_K3 = DWORD( $8F1BBCDC );
                SHA1_K4 = DWORD( $CA62C1D6 );
                { Maskes used in byte swap }
                LBMASK_HI = DWORD( $FF0000 );
                LBMASK_LO = DWORD( $FF00 );

            { SHA-1 message digest }
            procedure InitSHA1(var Context: TSHA1Context);
            procedure HashSHA1(var Digest : TSHA1Digest;
                                    const Buf; BufSize : Longint);
            procedure UpdateSHA1(var Context : TSHA1Context;
                                    const Buf; BufSize: Longint);
            procedure FinalizeSHA1(var Context: TSHA1Context;
                                    var Digest : TSHA1Digest);

            procedure StringHashSHA1(var Digest : TSHA1Digest;
                                    const Str : {$IFDEF LOCKBOXUNICODE}UnicodeString{$ELSE}AnsiString{$ENDIF}); stdcall;


            { Misc public utilities }
            {function Ran01(var Seed : LongInt) : LongInt;
            function Ran02(var Seed : LongInt) : LongInt;
            function Ran03(var Seed : LongInt) : LongInt;
            function Random32Byte(var Seed : LongInt) : Byte;
            function Random64Byte(var Seed : TInt64) : Byte;
            procedure ShrinkDESKey(var Key : TKey64);   }
            procedure XorMem(var Mem1;  const Mem2;  Count : Cardinal);
            function RolX(I, C : DWord) : DWord; register;

            procedure XorMemPrim(var Mem1;  const Mem2;  Count : Cardinal); register;
            asm
                push esi
                push edi

                mov  esi, eax         //esi = Mem1
                mov  edi, edx         //edi = Mem2

                push ecx              //save byte count
                shr  ecx, 2           //convert to dwords
                jz   @Continue

                cld
            @Loop1:                 //xor dwords at a time
                mov  eax, [edi]
                xor  [esi], eax
                add  esi, 4
                add  edi, 4
                dec  ecx
                jnz  @Loop1

            @Continue:              //handle remaining bytes (3 or less)
                pop  ecx
                and  ecx, 3
                jz   @Done

            @Loop2:                 //xor remaining bytes
                mov  al, [edi]
                xor  [esi], al
                inc  esi
                inc  edi
                dec  ecx
                jnz  @Loop2

            @Done:
                pop  edi
                pop  esi
            end;
            { -------------------------------------------------------------------------- }
            procedure XorMem(var Mem1;  const Mem2;  Count : Cardinal);
            begin
                XorMemPrim(Mem1, Mem2, Count);
            end;

            { == SHA-1 hashing routines ================================================ }
            procedure SHA1Clear( var Context : TSHA1Context );
            begin
                fillchar( Context, SizeOf( Context ), $00 );
            end;
            { -------------------------------------------------------------------------- }
            function SHA1SwapByteOrder( n : DWORD ) : DWORD;
            begin
                n := ( n shr 24 ) or (( n shr 8 ) and LBMASK_LO )
                         or (( n shl 8 ) and LBMASK_HI ) or ( n shl 24 );
                Result := n;
            end;
            { -------------------------------------------------------------------------- }
            procedure HashSHA1( var Digest : TSHA1Digest; const Buf; BufSize : Longint );
            var
                Context : TSHA1Context;
            begin
                InitSHA1( Context );
                UpdateSHA1( Context, Buf, BufSize );
                FinalizeSHA1( Context, Digest );
            end;
            { -------------------------------------------------------------------------- }
            {$IFDEF UNICODE}
            procedure StringHashSHA1W(var Digest : TSHA1Digest; const Str : UnicodeString);
            begin
                HashSHA1(Digest, Str[1], Length(Str) * SizeOf(WideChar));
            end;
            {$ENDIF}

            procedure StringHashSHA1A(var Digest : TSHA1Digest; const Str : AnsiString);
            begin
                HashSHA1(Digest, Str[1], Length(Str) * SizeOf(AnsiChar));
            end;
            { -------------------------------------------------------------------------- }
            procedure SHA1Hash( var Context : TSHA1Context );
            var
                A : DWord;
                B : DWord;
                C : DWord;
                D : DWord;
                E : DWord;

                X : DWord;
                W : array[ 0..79 ] of DWord;

                i : Longint;
            begin
                with Context do begin
                    sdIndex:= 0;
                    Move( sdBuf, W, Sizeof( W ));

                    // W := Mt, for t = 0 to 15 : Mt is M sub t
                    for i := 0 to 15 do
                        W[ i ]:= SHA1SwapByteOrder( W[ i ] );

                    // Transform Message block from 16 32 bit words to 80 32 bit words
                    // Wt, = ( Wt-3 xor Wt-8 xor Wt-13 xor Wt-16 ) rolL 1 : Wt is W sub t
                    for i:= 16 to 79 do
                        W[i]:= RolX( W[ i - 3 ] xor W[ i - 8 ] xor W[ i - 14 ] xor W[ i - 16 ], 1 );

                    A := sdHash[ 0 ];
                    B := sdHash[ 1 ];
                    C := sdHash[ 2 ];
                    D := sdHash[ 3 ];
                    E := sdHash[ 4 ];

                    // the four rounds
                    for i:= 0 to 19 do begin
                        X := RolX( A, 5 ) + ( D xor ( B and ( C xor D ))) + E + W[ i ] + SHA1_K1;
                        E := D;
                        D := C;
                        C := RolX( B, 30 );
                        B := A;
                        A := X;
                    end;

                    for i:= 20 to 39 do begin
                        X := RolX( A, 5 ) + ( B xor C xor D ) + E + W[ i ] + SHA1_K2;
                        E := D;
                        D := C;
                        C := RolX( B, 30 );
                        B := A;
                        A := X;
                    end;

                    for i:= 40 to 59 do begin
                        X := RolX( A, 5 ) + (( B and C ) or ( D and ( B or C ))) + E + W[ i ] + SHA1_K3;
                        E := D;
                        D := C;
                        C := RolX( B, 30 );
                        B := A;
                        A := X;
                    end;

                    for i:= 60 to 79 do
                    begin
                        X := RolX( A, 5 ) + ( B xor C xor D ) + E + W[ i ] + SHA1_K4;
                        E := D;
                        D := C;
                        C := RolX( B, 30 );
                        B := A;
                        A := X;
                    end;

                    sdHash[ 0 ]:= sdHash[ 0 ] + A;
                    sdHash[ 1 ]:= sdHash[ 1 ] + B;
                    sdHash[ 2 ]:= sdHash[ 2 ] + C;
                    sdHash[ 3 ]:= sdHash[ 3 ] + D;
                    sdHash[ 4 ]:= sdHash[ 4 ] + E;

                    FillChar( W, Sizeof( W ), $00 );
                    FillChar( sdBuf, Sizeof( sdBuf ), $00 );
                end;
            end;
            { -------------------------------------------------------------------------- }
            procedure SHA1UpdateLen( var Context : TSHA1Context; Len : DWord );
            begin
                Inc( Context.sdLo,( Len shl 3 ));
                if Context.sdLo < ( Len shl 3 ) then
                    Inc( Context.sdHi );
                Inc( Context.sdHi, Len shr 29 );
            end;
            { -------------------------------------------------------------------------- }
            procedure InitSHA1( var Context : TSHA1Context );
            begin
                SHA1Clear( Context );
                Context.sdHash[ 0 ] := SHA1_A;
                Context.sdHash[ 1 ] := SHA1_B;
                Context.sdHash[ 2 ] := SHA1_C;
                Context.sdHash[ 3 ] := SHA1_D;
                Context.sdHash[ 4 ] := SHA1_E;
            end;
            { -------------------------------------------------------------------------- }
            procedure UpdateSHA1( var Context : TSHA1Context; const Buf; BufSize: Longint );
            var
                PBuf: ^Byte;
            begin
                with Context do begin
                    SHA1UpdateLen( Context, BufSize );
                    PBuf := @Buf;
                    while BufSize > 0 do begin
                        if ( Sizeof( sdBuf ) - sdIndex ) <= DWord( BufSize ) then begin
                            Move( PBuf^, sdBuf[ sdIndex ], Sizeof( sdBuf ) - sdIndex );
                            Dec( BufSize, Sizeof( sdBuf ) - sdIndex );
                            Inc( PBuf, Sizeof( sdBuf ) - sdIndex );
                            SHA1Hash( Context );
                        end else begin
                            Move( PBuf^, sdBuf[ sdIndex ], BufSize );
                            Inc( sdIndex, BufSize );
                            BufSize := 0;
                        end;
                    end;
                end;
            end;

            { -------------------------------------------------------------------------- }
            procedure FinalizeSHA1( var Context : TSHA1Context; var Digest : TSHA1Digest );
            begin
                with Context do begin
                    sdBuf[ sdIndex ] := $80;

                    if sdIndex >= 56 then
                        SHA1Hash( Context );

                    PDWord( @sdBuf[ 56 ])^ := SHA1SwapByteOrder( sdHi );
                    PDWord( @sdBuf[ 60 ])^ := SHA1SwapByteOrder( sdLo );

                    SHA1Hash( Context );

                    sdHash[ 0 ] := SHA1SwapByteOrder( sdHash[ 0 ]);
                    sdHash[ 1 ] := SHA1SwapByteOrder( sdHash[ 1 ]);
                    sdHash[ 2 ] := SHA1SwapByteOrder( sdHash[ 2 ]);
                    sdHash[ 3 ] := SHA1SwapByteOrder( sdHash[ 3 ]);
                    sdHash[ 4 ] := SHA1SwapByteOrder( sdHash[ 4 ]);

                    Move( sdHash, Digest, Sizeof( Digest ));
                    SHA1Clear( Context );
                end;
            end;

            procedure StringHashSHA1(var Digest : TSHA1Digest; const Str : {$IFDEF LOCKBOXUNICODE}UnicodeString{$ELSE}AnsiString{$ENDIF}); export; stdcall;
            begin
                {$IFDEF LOCKBOXUNICODE}
                StringHashSHA1W(Digest, Str);
                {$ELSE}
                StringHashSHA1A(Digest, Str);
                {$ENDIF}
            end;

            EXPORTS
                StringHashSHA1;

            begin
            end.
```

Comment: This is a waste of time. There are good C# libraries for this. If you are going to present error messages present the entire message and tell us the line number and identify it in your code.

Comment: Obviously Id use the latest C# libraries if they provided the same results as this code. But they don't. 

As you say though, in future, I'll provide the full error message when requesting help.

Comment: It's because you aren't using the libraries correctly. Crazy to blame the libraries for your mistakes.

Comment: `UnicodeString` and `AnsiString` are not interop-safe types. So even if you manage to export `StringHashSHA1`, C# still won't be able to call it. You need to change the `Str` parameter to use `PWideChar`/`PAnsiChar` instead.

Comment: @Remy Thanks for pointing that out. You've no doubt saved me a lot of time and frustration.  I'll read up on interop safe types and PAnsichar and figure out what needs to be done..

Comment: @David You may be right, as mentioned on the second line of my post "I dont know much about delphi"
Which is why I posted on this forum... and I was fortunate enough to have some helpful people respond.
When taking a look at the libraries, I was unable to generate the same encryption string that the server service Im connecting to returns. Thats why I decided to try writing this dll.
Other forum members replied to my post and were tremendously helpful. Please study their replies, you could learn a lot from them.

Comment: On the other hand you will struggle to make progress if you believe that you are always right. The idea that the C# libraries can't do this and are defective is comically ridiculous. I was helping you, fat better than anyone else. Now it's on you. Be stubborn and Continue the belief that your code is perfect and the c# hashing libraries are broken. Or face up to reality. Your code is wrong. You, like all of us, are imperfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You lifted this code from a *unit*. That unit has separate interface and implementation sections, but you've merged them into a single section (as required for dpr files). There are functions that were *declared* in the implementation section, but without that section, Delphi interprets each function declaration instead as the start of another *nested* function. Eventually, we reach the end of the file inside several nested functions, and `exports` isn't allowed in that context.

Add `forward` onto the declarations at the top of your file (from `InitSHA1` through `RolX`) to mark them as declarations instead of definitions.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You're right, the code has come from a unit which I've tried to add to a dll. The delphi dll tutorials examples I've tried to follow  [link](http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=7416) seemed simple enough, but didn't cover things you've mentioned.

Comment: @Don rather than copy/paste the unit code into the DLL's DPR file and adjust it for compiling, you could have just added the original unit as-is to the DLL project and then include it in the DPR's `uses` clause.

Comment: @Remy Thanks for the suggestion. I'll keep that in mind if I ever need to use Delphi again. It'll keep things much simpler.

Comment: @Rob Thanks again for your help. Your forward suggestion enabled me to compile the DLL, although from what Remy says I still have a way to go before Im able to use the DLL.